# Differences between bldc sensorless motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am designing a driver for a sensorless bldc motor and I have found these two types of motor configurations.
I attach images.

Img 1:

[image]

Img 2:

[image]

Both are bldc sensorless motors?

How can I know the difference between one physically?

If the 3 power cables and 3 smaller ones come out of a motor, are we talking about the configuration of image 2 and if only 3 of the configuration of image 1 come out?

Comment: The second one has sensors, hall sensors to be precise.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič has it : one of those sensorless motors isn't sensorless. But if you need sensorless, ignore the sensors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: Both are bldc sensorless motors?

A: No, only the first one is a sensorless BLDC motor. The motor in image 2 has three Hall sensors (the ones enclosed in your red circle), thus it's not sensorless.

Q: How can I know the difference between one physically?

A: If you were to open up a sensored BLDC motor you will find three Hall sensors inside.  A sensored BLDC motor also has 3 "small" cables for the signals of the Hall sensors, whereas a sensorless BLDC motor has only the three "thick" power cables.

Q: If the 3 power cables and 3 smaller ones come out of a motor, are we talking about the configuration of image 2 and if only 3 of the configuration of image 1 come out?

A: Exactly

By the way, if you're designing a sensorless inverter you don't need to use the Hall sensor signals, you can just only ignore them.

Comment: The sensor cable usually has at least 5 wires because the Hall sensors need power.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the comment, I was just restricting the discussion to the presence/absence of the signal wires of the Hall sensors.